# external XML to own database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a problem with XML.

The format of the XML1 is following:

```
<users>
<user name="username1" status="a" id="123456" />
<user name="username2" status="b" id="123457" />
</users>
```

and the second XML contains another type of objects:

```
<objects>
<object ownedby="123456" where="1:2:3" objectname="Name" id="12341234" />
<object ownedby="123457" where="1:2:3" objectname="Name" id="12341234" />
and many more nodes like this with other values
</objects>
```

but sometimes it appears that a object has a children:

```
<object ownedby="123456" where="1:2:3" objectname="Name" id="12341234">
<subobject ownedby="123456" where="1:2:3" objectname="Name" id="12341235"/>
</object>
```

My problem is to fetch botch XML files and write the data into a database. I like to on which 'wheres' are the most kind of 'status B'-users, but thats another thing.

How can I import both XML files in 2 seperate database tables? I just don't get it until now. :(

Hope someone can help me to get this.

Note: the XMLs are not on my own server, I tried cURL but I probably not experienced enough with this kind of function.

I actually have this script running to feth it:

```
<?php
$url = 'link to the xml';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$xml = SimpleXMLElement($data);
foreach ($xml->user as $user) {

    echo '<h2>' . $user->coords . '</h2>';
    echo '<p>' . $user->player . '</p>';
```

Maybe someone can help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly what did you try already?

Comment: <?php

$url = '<link to XML>';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

# $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);


$xml = SimpleXMLElement($data);
foreach ($xml->user as $user) {

    echo '<h2>' . $user->id . '</h2>';
    echo '<p>' .  $user->status . '</p>';

Comment: I tried to just get a echo with the current value, but even this simple step has not worked :(

Comment: So you're trying to import it using PHP. I'd move the PHP code into the question.

Comment: @mzedeler Did it. Maybe its now more understandable.

Comment: Ok. Good. It doesn't compile. You're missing a bracket, but is that all you have left out?